# Hide horizontal scrollbar when content height is unknown

Tags: html, css, flexbox, scrollbar

I'm currently facing the issue of disabling the horizontal scrollbar cross-browser. The problem is, that the whole setting is embedded in a display flex environment and I don't know the actual (fixed) height of the content, because it's dynamic.

My current code looks like the following:

```
<div class="some-parent">
  <div class="wrapper-outer">
    <div class="wrapper-inner">
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

With the corresponding CSS:

```
.some-parent{
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}

.wrapper-outer{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper-inner{
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper-inner:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.content{
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

As I already said, the actual height of the `.content` element is unknown.

Is there a way to disable the horizontal scrollbar cross-browser? My current approach until now was always to set the height of the `.wrapper-inner` 20px higher than the height of the `.wrapper-outer` with `overflow: hidden`, but in this case unfortunately it's not working.

Here is the corresponding [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yp0og6hr/)

**Edit1:** The content should still be scrollable.

Comment: Yes, there is: `overflow-x: hidden`. It's cross browser. Part of [CSS level 2 Module, Rev. 1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visufx.html#overflow).

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I totally forgot about the important requirement, that the content should still be scrollable. So I rather want to hide the scrollbar, not disable.

Comment: There's no way to tell what type of scrollbar your current browser uses (whether it's drawn over or besides content). Also, different browsers have different sizes for scrollbars. Some paint them over the content, hiding them when not used. The only way to make sure is to hide the scrollbar altogether (disabling scroll) and implementing your own scrolling mechanism, which you can control visually. Or you could just allow `17px` bottom space for an eventual "hard" scrollbar and crop it using a wrapper. But this impairs usability. Big time. It's a no-no.

Comment: @V: https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/yp0og6hr/2/

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Your solution nailed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal scroll was enabled in the .wraper-inner class, you just have to disable it.

```
.wrapper-inner{
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Link to updated [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qvwk4Lkx/)

Comment: Sorry, my fault, I totally forgot about the important requirement, that the content should still be scrollable. So I rather want to hide the scrollbar, not disable.